# How to prevent android recaptcha dialog from dismssing onclick of outside?

Tags: android, kotlin, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am using reCAPTCHA v2 in my Android application for verifying genuine users.When any user clicks  on window outside the recaptcha it gets dismissed.I dont want to get it dismissed.Hot to achieve this?
Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: you haven't posted any code or a language tag so it's quite impossible for people to give you an answer

Comment: @a_local_nobody i am using it in  my Android application

Comment: that's doesn't tell anyone if it's using java or kotlin